# Google Chrome: can't access .localhost subdomains entered in hosts file on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser

Over my `/etc/hosts` file I have the following entry:

```
192.168.10.80 myapp.localhost
```

When I visit the url `http://myapp.localhost` on the Firefox browser it correctly shows my application running in a vagrant. But on chrome or any chromium-based (Brave browser, Chromium) is fails to show.

Do you know why that happens?

I looked over theese solutions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30476300/4706711
- [Why can't Google Chrome resolve subdomains from /private/etc/hosts?](https://superuser.com/q/1094921/860667)
- [Google Chrome can't access localhost domains](https://superuser.com/q/646304/860667)

Also when I try to disable asyncronous DNS I cannot find that option:

[image: Asyncronous DNS not found]

In the duplicate answers I cannot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Chrome ignoring /etc/hosts on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/648133/why-is-chrome-ignoring-etc-hosts-on-os-x)

Comment: Try chrome with the parameter of `--enable-async-dns`.

Comment: But this parameter ENABLES dns I want to be disabled.

Comment: But for some reason in MS Windows works fine and it does not ingore the `/etc/hosts` file? Does MS Windows have some sort of internal DNS and the google chrome uses that?

Comment: As given in the link I gave, this is just the way Chrome works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use `.localhost` subdomains follow this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565311/4706711).